# Прописная или строчная буква в сокращённых (усечённых) названиях

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия, сокращения, условные-сокращения

Скажите, какое существует правило по поводу употребления прописных букв в сокращённых вариантах составных названий? Верно ли, что выбор прописной либо строчной буквы зависит от того, с какой буквы пишется это слово в полном названии? Вот примеры, верны ли они? Какому правилу следовать?

1. В Саратовском государственном университете состоялось мероприятие международного масштаба. Профессор сказал, что это повысит авторитет Саратовского. (Саратовский государственный университет = Саратовский.)
2. В "Центре офтальмологии" открылась вакансия; "Центр" приглашает к сотрудничеству санитарку. ("Центр офтальмологии" = "Центр".)
3. Наш Международный институт печати открывает двери для будущих журналистов и редакторов. Скоро в институте печати будет объявлен набор на эти специальности. (Международный институт печати = институт печати.)

Comment: ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, не меняйте своего решения, если вы уже приняли ответ. У нас это НЕ ПРИНЯТО. Я вообще часто дополняю уже принятые ответы, но только для того, чтобы сообщить новую информацию.

Comment: А лучше сначала ставить плюсики-стрелочки на все полезные ответы, а спустя какое-то время выбрать один из них галочкой.

Comment: Иногда ответы принимаются сразу, но при этом автор вопроса должен быть УВЕРЕН в том, что его проблема полностью решена, никаких сомнений не осталось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой теме важен **индивидуальный подход и разумный выбор**, а также знакомство с практикой употребления конкретного имени. Очень нежелательна самодеятельность и придумывание сокращенных названий.

Также важно понимать **принципы построения** составных имен. С прописной буквы пишутся три варианта: первое слово, слово с условным названием и входящие в сложное название другие имена собственные.

Очень часто сокращение строится на использовании **условного имени** в качестве первого слова, например: Государственный академический Большой театр — Большой театр, Государственный литературный музей — Литературный музей, Центральный дом художника — Дом художника. Здесь условными, а не реальными именами являются слова ***большой, дом*** — соответственно, они пишутся с прописной буквы в сокращенных названиях.

А слово ***литературный*** почему считается условным? Имеется в виду центральный музей литературы, единственный в своем роде. А в названиях местных музеев это слово будет считаться реальным и писаться со строчной буквы.

Некоторые сокращения используются только в **реальной разговорной речи**: гулять на Патриарших прудах — гулять на Патриарших; ходить по Воробьёвым горам — ходить по Воробьёвым. В таком виде они понятны окружающим.

Но никаких **гор и прудов** (это уже перебор) — родовые названия в сокращенных именах нежелательно писать с прописной буквы, даже если они понятны участникам частного разговора. Это уже чисто авторская орфография, обобщать ее и считать правилом не следует.

Answer (score 2):

Академический справочник Лопатина, раздел "Орфография":

> § 190. С прописной буквы пишется первое (или единственное) слово
> усеченного названия, если оно употребляется вместо полного, напр.:
> Государственная дума — Дума, Государственный литературный музей —
> Литературный музей, Центральный дом художника — Дом художника, Большой
> зал Московской консерватории — Большой зал Консерватории, Московский
> государственный институт международных отношений — Институт
> международных отношений.

Третий пример неверен, должно быть: *Институт печати*.

Comment: Хорошо, а как быть, когда, скажем, название местности? Гулять на Патриарших прудах — гулять на Патриарших — гулять на Прудах (именно этих)? Ходить по Воробьёвым горам — ходить по Воробьёвым — ходить по Горам (именно этим)?

Comment: @ShiKomarishe насколько я понимаю, именно так.

Comment: user200790, всё-таки "Грамота.ру" говорит, что приведённое вами правило распространяется только "на названия органов власти, учреждений, организаций, научных, учебных и зрелищных заведений, обществ, политических партий и объединений (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309954). То есть в случае Патриарших прудов верно будет пруды, Воробьёвы горы — горы.